# How to center the text in PHPExcel merged cell

Tags: php, phpexcel

How to center text "test"?

**This is my code:**

```
<?php
    /** Error reporting */
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

    /** Include PHPExcel */
    require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, 1, "test");
    $sheet->mergeCells('A1:B1');
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save("test.xlsx");
```

**Output Excel document:**

[image]

Answer (score 115, accepted):

if you want to align only this cells, you can do something like this:

```
    $style = array(
        'alignment' => array(
            'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
        )
    );

    $sheet->getStyle("A1:B1")->applyFromArray($style);
```

But, if you want to apply this style to all cells, try this:

```
    $style = array(
        'alignment' => array(
            'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
        )
    );

    $sheet->getDefaultStyle()->applyFromArray($style);
```

Comment: in latest PhpExcel it works like this:  $style = array(
            'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
    );  that is WITHOUT the 'alignment' array key

Comment: To center allign column values use: $objPHPExcelSheet->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

Comment: for laravel 5.x use `\PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER` instead `PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER`

Answer (score 18):

```
<?php
    /** Error reporting */
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

    /** Include PHPExcel */
    require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, 1, "test");
    $sheet->mergeCells('A1:B1');
    $sheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:B1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save("test.xlsx");
?>
```

Comment: **You can set VERTICAL Alignment too**
`setVERTICAL(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);`

Answer (score 11):

The solution is to set the cell style through this function:

```
$sheet->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->applyFromArray(
    array('horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,)
);
```

### Full code

```
<?php
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, 1, "test");
$sheet->mergeCells('A1:B1');
$sheet->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->applyFromArray(
    array('horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,)
);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save("test.xlsx");
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

We can also set the vertical alignment with using this way

```
$style_cell = array(
   'alignment' => array(
       'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
       'vertical' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
   ) 
);
```

with this cell set the vertically aligned into the middle.

Answer (score 2):

When using merged columns, I got it centered by using PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER_CONTINUOUS instead of PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER

Answer (score 0):

```
// this will work in  Excel2007
$object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, 1, "UTI - AMC  LTD.  - DOFA ");
$style = array(
'alignment' => array(
'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
'vertical' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
)
);

$object->getDefaultStyle()->applyFromArray($style);
$object->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:H1');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using **applyFromArray** or **setHorizontal** and **setVertical** to setting alignment, like codes below:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1")->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(\PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1")->getAlignment()->setVertical(\PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
```

OR

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1")->getAlignment()->applyFromArray(
    array(
        "horizontal" => \PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER, 
        "vertical" => \PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER
    )
);
```