# PhpExcel: center align text in a single cell in a set of merged cells

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to create a xls file. I have merged the cells (B2:E2), but I want the text entered in B2 to be horizantally center aligned in the B2 cell only. It gets center aligned in the merged cell.

```
$sheet_obj->getStyle('B2')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(
    PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER
);
```

Comment: Can you do it in Excel itself? If you can't then it can't be done in PHPExcel. I can't really see how it would be possible. When merged, it's seen as a single cell, so centring would be in that context.

Comment: You can't. Though you could achieve a similar visual effect by merging cells C2:E2, and setting the border between B2 and C2 to match the cell background colour so that it looked as though it was part of the merge group

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285884/how-to-center-the-text-in-phpexcel-merged-cell

Answer (score 5):

hope this helps

`$sheet_obj->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G2')
            ->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);`